# A button is hidden by keyboard when it is shown

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android application, with a numerical keypad screen.

I have this screen:

[image: keypad screen, keyboard closed]

But when keyboard is shown, this is what I see:

[image: keypad screen, keyboard opened]

The "Aceptar" button is hidden by keyboard.

This is the layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo_5"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textMessages"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textSubMessages"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkRemenberPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editSecondNum"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:text="@string/layout_check_remember_password" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAccept"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkRemenberPassword"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:onClick="onAcceptClick"
        android:text="@string/btn_accept" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editFirstNum"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="191dp"
        android:ems="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:minLines="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editFourthNum"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editThirdNum"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editThirdNum"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="34dp"
        android:ems="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:minLines="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editThirdNum"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editSecondNum"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editSecondNum"
        android:layout_marginRight="42dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editFourthNum"
        android:ems="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:minLines="1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editSecondNum"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editFirstNum"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editFirstNum"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/editFirstNum"
        android:ems="1"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLength="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:minLines="1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**How can I avoid this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

to your tag in the AndroidManifest file, or if that doens't work, maybe try adding it to your layout xml file.

Answer (score 2):

In your AndroidManifest.xml trying adding the following:

```
<activity  android:name="com.YOUR.ACTIVITY"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >    <--add this bit
</activity>
```

Comment: Sorry. I've tried, but it doesn't work. I have added the layout to my question.

Comment: Did you add it in the xml file for the specific activity? This is how I resolved the exact same issue in my app...

Comment: Yeah sorry that's what I meant, just missed out manifest. I always find Lars Vogel's blog very handy for Android help: http://blog.vogella.com/2010/10/25/android-windowsoftinputmode/ He takes a similar approach to me.